# invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ error

Tags: c++

i have defined the below two types,

when i use them in the below snippet, i get this error:

invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
     tmp = strstr(tmp, delim);

```
typedef std::vector<PCCHAR> STR_VEC; /
typedef const char * PCCHAR;
typedef PCCHAR const CPCCHAR;

STR_VEC split(CPCCHAR delim, CPCCHAR buf) 
{
STR_VEC arr;
char *tmp = strdup(buf);
while(1)
{
arr.push_back(tmp);
tmp = strstr(tmp, delim);
if(!tmp)
  break;
*tmp = '\0';
 tmp += strlen(delim);
}
return arr;
}
```

Comment: Why all of the `C` stuff in your C++ code?  What's wrong with simply using `std::string` instead of `strdup`, `strlen`, etc.?

Comment: Why are you mixing use `char*` with `std::string`? Just using `std::string` you can achive what you want a lot easier.

Comment: the platform i am developing onis restrictive..(intel sgx enclaves)...

Comment: Why do you make the code harder to read by hiding the pointers behind opaque aliases? Also, your example lacks definition for `STR_VEC`.

Comment: *the platform i am developing one is restrictive* -- And what is `STR_VEC`?  Is it a `std::vector`?  If so, then why there isn't a `std::string`?

Comment: Intel SGX Enclaves do not prohibit use of the C++ standard library.

Comment: typedef std::vector<PCCHAR> STR_VEC; /

Comment: intel sgx do not prohibit ALL c++ standard libraries. and (most of)the ones that you can call from within an enclave are enclave specifc implementations of the same libraries

Comment: @ijuio put the definitions into the code in the question, so that it compiles (except for the compilation error that is supposed to be reproduced).

Comment: i added this to the code to resolve the error:   const char *tmp1 = (const char *) tmp;      tmp1 = (const char*) strstr(tmp, delim);
for some reason, i thought i had tried it our earlier with no avail..thanks for the suggestions

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://ideone.com/8tZcGO).

Comment: It looks like your definition of strstr may not be POSIX standard. It seems to return `const char*` when it should be `char*`. It should be OK to cast away `const` in this case: `tmp = const_cast<char*>(strstr(...));`

Comment: @ijuio If that has solved your problem please post it as an answer and accept it, as if may be helpful to someone who has managed to arrive at the same configuration as you such that this bug is reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone is encoutering the same error, the below fixed it for me:

const char tmp1 = (const char *) tmp;
tmp1 = (const char) strstr(tmp, delim);